# When will spring-authorization-server support Spring Boot 2.6.x and spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I don't want to repeat previous other threads. I just don't see this being tracked anywhere although it is a known issue. If it is tracked, please point me in the right direction.

Currently spring-authorization-server works with Spring Boot 2.5.x. It is known that there is an inconsistency with the spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client implementation and the Jwt tokens and that of spring-authorization-server.

This means you can successfully run spring-authorization-server with Spring Boot 2.6.x BUT you cannot add the dependency spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client.

And that's where I'm stuck. I wanted to implement a federated security example using the federated sample located in the codebase here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver

```
2022-04-25 14:14:34.067 ERROR 54601 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] io.undertow.request                      : UT005023: Exception handling request to /oauth2/token

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JoseHeader from class org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.JwtGenerator (org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JoseHeader and org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.JwtGenerator are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.JwtGenerator.generate(JwtGenerator.java:130) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.2.3.jar:0.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.JwtGenerator.generate(JwtGenerator.java:59) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.2.3.jar:0.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.DelegatingOAuth2TokenGenerator.generate(DelegatingOAuth2TokenGenerator.java:60) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.2.3.jar:0.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:212) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.2.3.jar:0.2.3]
```

What's the status of this inconsistency?

Comment: You can track progress in issue #594, [Release 0.3.0 Checklist](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/594).

Comment: Thank you @SteveRiesenberg. Looks like v0.3.0 is right around the corner. Will wait for this.

Comment: Just a note that this release is available and the checklist is completed.

Comment: Yes it is!! Already upgraded to 0.3.0 and Spring Boot 2.7.0. Thank you @SteveRiesenberg for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can move the security-oauth2-authorization-server dependency
before any other spring-boot dependencies declaration inside the pom, that will force classloader to load the org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JoseHeader from security-oauth2-authorization-server.
Please read https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/518#issuecomment-1017332290

Answer (score 0):

Spring Authorization Server v0.3.0 has been released and there is no longer a discrepancy between SAS and Spring Security OAuth.

‍♂️